# Combine regular expressions to extract data in C#

Tags: c#, regex, tuples

I have a string that contains HTML that is hard coded to be in the following format:

```
<span class="Marker" id="a">Some text 1</span><br>
<span class="Marker" id="b">Some text 2</span><br>
<span class="Marker" id="c">Some text 2</span><br>
<p class="inactive">Some text 4</p>
<p class="inactive">Some text 5</p>
```

My goal is to iterate over each line and:

1. Extract the text.
2. Check if the string contains **class="Marker"**

Store this information in a list.

I want to first extract only the text from the HTML and save them to a list so I have the following:

```
//(?<=>)  -> Lookbehind
//(?=<)   -> Lookahead
var matches = Regex.Matches(htmlString, "(?<=>)([^<]+)(?=<)");
List<string> list = new List<string>();

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
   list.Add(match.Value);
}
```

This works as expected.  Now I want to detect if each string contains the string class="Marker" so I have the following:

```
var classes = Regex.Matches(html, "(?<=<span class=\")([A-Za-z]+)(?=\")");
List<bool> isPresentList = new List<bool>();
foreach (Match cl in classes)
{
    bool isPresent = cl.ToString().Equals("Marker", StringComparison.Ordinal);
    isPresentList.Add(isPresent);
}
```

This also works as expected but I want to be able to do this in all one step if possible.

Is there a way to combine the Regex filters together so I am returned the text and if the Marker is there or not (In a tuple for example)?

Comment: Regexes are a very poor tool to handle XML/HTML. Why not use one designed specifically for it? E.g. https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: This does my job as the HTML will not change from this format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a RegEx like the one below?

```
    <([\w]*) class="(\w*)"[ =\w"]*>([ \w]*)<\/\1>
```

which includes a back-reference `\1` to a group that captures the tag name `([\w]*)`. The marker (class name) is also captured with `class="(\w*)"`.

If your text inside the html tags is likely to contain punctuation, you would want to change the `[ \w]` section to something else, for example `(.*?)` would capture any characters using a [Lazy Quantifier](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html).

See: https://regex101.com/r/Ufluqs/2 for an example using the data you have provided.

**Warning:** You may have trouble with a RegEx approach for a number of reasons, for example if the html attributes are written in a different order, or nested html tags.

Comment: I have updated the RegEx for you, i think it's closer to what you wanted.

Comment: Your solution is working perfectly on the web link, but when I use it in C# as follows  var matches = Regex.Matches(html, "<([\\w]*) class=\"(\\w*)\"[ =\\w\"]*>((.*?)*)<\\/\\1>"); the string value returned is the original string e.g "<span class=\"Marker\" id=\"c\">Some text 2</span><br>".  Is there a way it can return the individual groups? i.e "Marker" and the "Some text 2" ?

Comment: Try the [Match.Groups property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to retrive the individual groups.

Comment: Quick question, I have changed the last group to ((.*?)*) as my string can contain punctuation.  What is the need for two sets of parenthesis? If the inner regex means "any character zero or more times" then why the need for the extra * after it?

Comment: I think you are right and you don't need the extra set of parenthesis.